# How to disallow multiple parallel user sessions per login in ZF2?

Tags: php, session, authentication, zend-framework, zfcuser

I'm currently facing the situation, that the `ZendFramework2` `ZFCuser-Module` does not have any options to prevent a user from logging in from two devices at the same time.

We recently had a case, that two people were "account-sharing" and accidentally deleted each others data. Since I did not build the application to account for this kind of resource conflicts, I need to prevent this behaviour now.

Is there any module or easy possibility out there to prevent account-sharing in `Zend Framework 2 with ZFCUser`?

The docs and SO and all sorts of ZF2 blogs somehow appear to never have come across this type of problem...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zend but you can add a column to your database that tracks the IP of the user or some piece of detail which is unique per device (I would offer MAC address but it cannot be achieved)?

Comment: Something like this would be possible, but I cannot believe this rather far developed Framework does not have anything in the shelf to tackle this kind of problem. I refuse to believe this problem is super special!

But thanks for the advice... This will be the direction I'm heading, if no one has an elaborate answer :-(

Comment: @Sammy Same problem for me have you found any solution? ZF2

Comment: Hey @rocky, I'm sorry, but we couldn't find an elegant solution for this. I think we added a section to the terms & conditions to inform the users about possible side-effects and logged the used IP-adresses to assist our problem-analysis.

Comment: @Sammy I added my idea if it helps then do support

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the functionality of limiting the number of sessions for the same user.

However, my solution (code below) doesn't provide any data-protected layer in order to restrict CRUD operation performed from another session.

I think you can achieve this if you restrict operation based on user_id and session_id

**DB**

| id | user_id | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00m5nqcvpk9bhqv7rbllq5hsi4 | 198 | 14 |
| 34ssnqcvpk9xxqv7rbll4354fdf | 123 | 42 |

```
id will be session_id (PHP SID)
```

**Method**

```
/**
     * 
     * @param int $userId
     * @param int $clientId
     * @return type
     */
    public function validateActiveSession($userId, $clientId) {
        if (empty($userId)) {
            $userId = $this->getResourceManager()->getIdentity()->getId();
        }

        if (empty($clientId)) {
            $clientId = $this->getResourceManager()->getIdentity()->getClientId();
        }

        $sessionManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Session\SessionManager');
        $id = $sessionManager->getId();

        $userModel = $this->getResourceManager()->getuserModel();

        $sIdUserExist = $userModel->getUserActiveSession('', '', $id);
        if (empty($sIdUserExist)) {
            $userModel->addUserSessionBySidAndUserClientId($id, $userId, $clientId);
        }
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public function addUserSessionBySidAndUserClientId($sessionId, $userId, $clientId)
    {
        $em = $this->_em->getConnection();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `user_session`(`id`, `user_id`, `client_id`) VALUES (:id,:user_id,:client_id)";
        $params = array('id' => $sessionId, 'user_id' => $userId, 'client_id' => $clientId);
        $stmt = $em->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt->execute($params);
    }

public function getActiveUserSession($userId, $clientId, $sessionId)
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');
        $rsm->addScalarResult('user_id', 'user_id');

        $userIdClause = $clientIdClause = $andClause = $sessionIdClause = '';

        if (!empty($userId)) {
            $userIdClause = 'user_id = :user_id';
        }

        if (!empty($clientId)) {
            $clientIdClause = ' and client_id = :client_id';
        }

        if (!empty($userId) && !empty($sessionId)) {
            $andClause = ' and ';
        }

        if (!empty($sessionId)) {
            $sessionIdClause = 'id = :id';
        }

        $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('SELECT id,user_id FROM user_session WHERE ' . $userIdClause . $clientIdClause . $andClause . $sessionIdClause, $rsm);

        if (!empty($userId)) {
            $query->setParameter('user_id', $userId);
        }

        if (!empty($clientId)) {
            $query->setParameter('client_id', $clientId);
        }
        if (!empty($sessionId)) {
            $query->setParameter('id', $sessionId);
        }

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

**once user logged-in check for active sessions**

```
$sameActiveUser = count($userModel->getActiveUserSession($userId, $clientId, ''));
    
if ($sameActiveUser == 2) { //already 2 active session than restrict 3rd
   return "session already present";
} else {
   $this->validateActiveSession($userId, $clientId);
}
```